# Ajax AutoComplete Feature with Prototype and Django

Tags: python, ajax, django, autocomplete, prototypejs

I would like to integrate Django, and the JavaScript prototype library to create an autocomplete feature for a form. Can anyone recommend a prototype feature that has been tried with Django? There is [this code](http://www.devbridge.com/projects/autocomplete/) and [also this](http://www.brandspankingnew.net/archive/2006/08/ajax_auto-suggest_auto-complete.html) and I'm wondering if anyone would recommend one over the other for use with Django. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I downloaded the code from this [site](http://www.beauscott.com/examples/autocomplete/doc/examples.html)
and followed the directions there, which was straightforward. Just include the prototype.js, scriptaculous.js, and AutoComplete.js files. Then copy paste from the directions, and change the url from `assets/ac.php?m=text&s=` to `?m=text&s=` or even just `?s=` if one query parameter is all you need.

```
    <input type="text" id="my_ac3" name="my_ac" size="45" autocomplete="off"/> 
    <script type="text/javascript"> 
    new AutoComplete('my_ac3', '?s=', { delay: 0.25, resultFormat: AutoComplete.Options.RESULT_FORMAT_TEXT }); 
    </script>
```

On the server side, in your view function for that page, start the function with:

```
    if request.is_ajax():
        #match the users input here, perhaps using data from your database and/or regular expressions
        text = #response text to return, in my case since I chose Options.RESULT_FORMAT_TEXT as my resultFormat, it's a string where each autocomplete item is separated by '\n'
        return HttpResponse(text, mimetype='text/plain')  # mimetype is text here in my case
```

Then place the rest of the view function under an else clause.